# A QR factorization of a $A - Qe_1 e_1^* R$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthogonality, matrix-decomposition, orthogonal-matrices

I'm trying to solve the following problem of a 'perturbed' QR factorization in preparation for a test of mine.

**Q:** Let $A \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times m}, m \geq n$ have a thin $QR$ factorization $A = QR$. Determine the $QR$ factorization of $A - Q e_1 e_1^* R$ in terms of the $QR$ factorization of $A$.

**Attempted Solution:** This new matrix has an interesting structure, that is:
$$
Q e_1 e_1^* R
=
\begin{bmatrix}
Q(:,1)R(1,1) & \dots & Q(:,1)R(1,n)
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where $Q(:,1)$ is referring to the first column of $Q$. This tells us that in fact:
$$
A - Q e_1 e_1^* R
=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & A(:,2) - Q(:,1)R(1,2) & \dots & A(:,n) - Q(:,1)R(1,n)
\end{bmatrix}
$$
So this perturbed matrix is $A$ with the first column zeroed out and with some '$QR$' pieces removed. However, I don't see an easy way to directly find the $QR$ factorization of this? Is there perhaps an argument I can make from the orthogonality of $Q(:,1)$ with respect to the rest of $Q$, and then perhaps there's a argument of how to augment the original $Q$ to triangularize this?

Any thoughts?

EDIT: I have discovered via running an example in octave, that $Q^*(A - Qe_1 e_1^* R)$ actually seems to produce an upper triangular matrix, will report back if this results in something interesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm foolish, this was actually easy.

Going off of my edit, we see that:
\begin{align*}
Q^*(A - Q e_1 e_1^* R)
&=
R - e_1 e_1^* R
\end{align*}
which is simply $R$ with its first row zeroed out, and critically is upper triangular. Thus $A - Qe_1 e_1^* R = Q (R - e_1 e_1^* R)$ is a QR factorization (which I could have alternatively seen by factoring a $Q$ out of the original matrix...)

Whoops.